# Отключить MAC - фильтрацию

Tags: windows, сеть

Проблема такая: у меня есть ADSL-модем с адресом (192.168.1.1) и к нему подключен Wi-Fi роутер с адресом (192.168.0.1) . У Wi-Fi роутера есть ограничитель по подключению новых устройств (МАС фильтрация). И я не могу теперь отключить эту фильтрацию. Пытаюсь подключиться к нему через браузер (192.168.0.1)  - безрезультатно. Какой выход?

Comment: А при чём тут windows?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у Вас Wi-Fi роутер адрес получает автоматически от модема. По этому сейчас у него адрес вид 192.168.1.ххх . Необходимо подключится к ADSL-модему и узнать кокой адрес он выдал роутеру, после чего подключаться на него. Какой адрес получает устройство с которого Вы пытаетесь подключиться к роутеру ?

Comment: Учитывая что таких адресов всего 255, можно перебрать.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно в роутерах отключено управление через wi-fi в целях безопасности. Подключайся через медный провод.